# Merge 2 rows into one row in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to merge 2 rows in 1 in SQL Server.

This is what I have:

```
+---------------+-------+--------+
| Part Number   | Code  | value  |
+---------------+-------+--------+
|     1         |  00   |   12   |
|     1         |  01   |   21   |
+---------------+-------+--------+
```

This is what I want :

```
+---------------+-------+--------+
| Part Number   | Code  | value  |
+---------------+-------+--------+
|       1       |  00   |   33   |
```

I want that remain only the code 00.

Comment: You want the first record in `Code` column or the minimun value? What have you tried?

Comment: Please put more effort in your question and elaborate how you get from the source to the requested result + instead of describe your table you should post query to create the table and queries to insert the sample data.

Comment: @bradbury9 i want the first record in the 'code' column.

Comment: @RonenAriely I want to merge my old records, subdivided in '00' and '01' , all in one record '00' .

Comment: I was uncertain on proposing an answer using row_number() over partition or a simple group by. Anyway this question is most probably already answered

Comment: I cannot understand the rules to consolidate the rows. Please explain the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT [Part Number], MIN(Code), SUM(value)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY [Part Number]
```

Comment: @EmanueleVerderame, it does not matter since 00 string is before 01 string

Comment: But i got this error : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation .Thank you for your time !

Comment: You have more records in the table and one of more of those recors has `NULL` in the `Code` or `value` columns. If the null is in the `value` column you could change the `SUM` aggregate function into `SUM(isnull(value, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP BY` clause

you can try

```
SELECT PartNumber, MIN(Code), SUM(value) FROM parts GROUP BY PartNumber
```

Comment: @EmanueleVerderame, it does not matter since 00 string is before 01 string

Comment: It will still work, since if you sort it out, 00, will come first before 01

Comment: But i got this error :
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation .Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

@EmanueleVerderame, This is a mock up below, to show you how to prevent errors.
It seems some column, either Code or Value has NULL/Blank values.

```
DECLARE @parts TABLE (PartNumber INT, Code Char(2), Value INT)
INSERT INTO @parts
SELECT 1,'00', 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '01', 21 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, NULL, 5
--+---------------+-------+--------+
--| Part Number   | Code  | value  |
--+---------------+-------+--------+
--|     1         |  00   |   12   |
--|     1         |  01   |   21   |
--|     2         |       |   5    |
--+---------------+-------+--------+

SELECT PartNumber, MIN(isnull(Code, '00') ), SUM(isnull(value, 0))  FROM 
@parts 
GROUP BY PartNumber
```

Comment: which is pretty much the essence of my comment in the question, but there is no feedback when I adviced about those null values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only first result then you should use `where rownum = 1`